# как поменять направление движения объекта при столкновении с чем-либо Unity 3D и сделать этот процесс бесконечным

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio-code

У меня есть вражеский куб, и он должен передвигаться сначала в одном направлении и потом возвращаться, и так бесконечно

вот код врага:

```
private void Awake() {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}


private void FixedUpdate() {
    rb.AddForce(0, 0, runSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
    GameObject colliderWith = other.gameObject;
    if (colliderWith.tag == "PushEnemy") {
        runSpeed *= -negative;
    }
    GameObject coliderWith = other.gameObject;
    if(colliderWith.tag == "NegativePushEnemy") {
        runSpeed *= 1;
    }
```

Проблема с передвижением решена, но этот процесс происходит 1 раз. Мне нужно чтобы объект бесконечно передвигался из стороны в сторону по z.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Моя 3D игра это аналог 2D игры Red ball 4. В этой игре враги это черные кубы, которые на начальных уровнях передвигаются лишь по x и -x. В моем случае (т.к. это трехмерная игра) вражеский куб должен передвигаться по z и по -z и так бесконечно из стороны в сторону (вперед, назад, вперед,назад). Моя проблема лишь в том что куб выполняет это передвижение не бесконечно. Из исходного положения идет по z вперед, соприкоснувшись с триггером идет по -z назад, затем соприкоснувшись  триггером напротив опять идет по z вперед, доходит до 1 триггера И ОСТАНАВЛИВАЕТСЯ, в этом моя проблема

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, если всякие вычисления по типу движения и вращения объектов находятся в `FixedUpdate()`, то `Time.deltaTime` только всё испортит. Советую заменить `rb.AddForce(0, 0, runSpeed * Time.deltaTime);` на `rb.AddForce(0, 0, runSpeed);`, а вот если бы у тебя была функция `Update()`, вместо `FixedUpdate()`, то `Time.deltaTime` был бы нужен.

Во-вторых, если у куба есть RigidBody и любой Collider **И** у объекта, в который врезается куб тоже есть свои RigidBody и любой Collider, то нужно использовать `OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)`, вместо `OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)`, так как мы хотим сделать что-то, когда объекты ВРЕЗАЮТСЯ друг в друга, а не входят друг в друга (Учитывая то, что в компоненте коллайдера не поставлена галочка около "Is Trigger")

В-третьих, в твоём случае при столкновении куба об что-то надо написать всего ОДИН раз это:

```
GameObject colliderWith = other.gameObject;
if (colliderWith.tag == "PushEnemy") {
    runSpeed *= -1;
}
```

Если написать это дважды, как сделал ты, то условие будет выполняться дважды, а значит runSpeed будет умножаться на -1 дважды, а значит направление движения куба не изменится.

В общем вот (*вроде*) правильный код:

```
private void Awake()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.AddForce(0, 0, runSpeed);
}
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    GameObject colliderWith = other.gameObject;
    if (colliderWith.tag == "PushEnemy")
    {
        runSpeed *= -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Не чувак, куба колбасит по полной

Comment: Если ты скопировал мой код, который в конце, то он не правильный. Только что заметил, что я использовал OnTriggerEnter()...